# A good Java wrapper for TAPI 2?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, tapi, jtapi

Does anyone know of a good JNI/Java wrapper for TAPI 2?

I need to interact with the Avaya phones on the desks of my users for a CRM web application (based on GWT), and all computers have a TAPI 2 driver already installed (no TAPI 3 driver is available). Unfortunately the phone server does not produce events for calls-in-progress in a centralised form, or provide an API for initiating calls centrally.

I plan to use a signed Java Applet in the background of the web app to connect via TAPI and interact with the GWT client code via GWTAI.

I found the JTAPI implementations XTAPI and GJTAPI - but they are convoluted (due to the big differences between JTAPI and TAPI), buggy, and don't implement all TAPI functionality (e.g. XTAPI only provides 2 lines of call info of the dozen available).

[Helen Warn's C# Wrapper](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32569273/helen-warns-c-wrapper.aspx) provides a fantastic wrapper for TAPI 2 in C#, that does exactly what I want, providing direct access to the simple TAPI 2 interface. The only problem is that embedding an ActiveX control in a web page is off-limits as we really don't want to be locked into IE!

So it looks like I'm going to have to port Helen Warn's wrapper to Java using JNI? (not a trivial task).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Despite similar-looking names, TAPI and JTAPI are two completely different APIs. With regards to Avaya, TAPI is used to control Avaya IP Office series PBX and softphone applications running off Communication Manager (formerly Definity) series PBX. JTAPI is, in fact, a Java implementation of Novell's TSAPI protocol that is used to control Avaya Communication Manager PBX directly (not via phones). Centralized event notification and call control is provided via Application Enablement Services gateway (formerly Avaya CT) with variety of protocols and APIs, including JTAPI.

Hope it was helpful.

Regards,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use one of the following tools, among others, to make the task more trivial.

- SWIG: http://www.swig.org/
- JNA: http://jna.java.net/
- JavaCPP: http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/

Being the author of the third there, I recommend that one :)